# What if epsilon, delta are rational?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

The precise formulation of the (ε, δ)-definition of limit as written here in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit doesn't specify which kind of number the epsilon, delta are.

I wonder if it matters.

Comment: It is specified, they're real numbers.

Comment: I think so, too. But my question particularly asks if the intended meaning changes if they are rational, though.

Comment: NO! it does not impact anything if $\epsilon, \delta$ are changed to assume rational values. The definition of limit is based on the idea that field of numbers being used should satisfy Archimedean principle. The power of real numbers over rational numbers is not seen in the definition of limit, but rather in existence theorems concerning limits (for example monotone and bounded sequences are convergent). BTW +1 for raising this interesting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \ell$, then for all (real) $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a (real) $\delta > 0$, such that $|x - a| < \delta$ gives $|f(x) - \ell| < \epsilon$. Hence, for $\epsilon \in \Bbb Q \cap(0,\infty)$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - a| < \delta$ gives $|f(x) - \ell| < \epsilon$. Now choose $\delta '$ to be a rational number such that $0 < \delta ' < \delta$. Then, $|x - a| < \delta '$ gives $|f(x) - \ell| < \epsilon$.

Conversely, suppose that for all $\epsilon \in \Bbb Q \cap (0,\infty)$, there exists $\delta \in \Bbb Q \cap (0,\infty)$ such that $|x - a| < \delta$ gives $|f(x) - \ell| < \epsilon$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be any real number. Let $\epsilon '$ be a rational number such that $0 < \epsilon ' < \epsilon$. Then, there exists a $\delta > 0$ (rational, but this is immaterial) such that $|x - a| < \delta$ gives $|f(x) - \ell| < \epsilon ' $, from which we get $|f(x) - \ell| < \epsilon$.

Conclusion: the two are equivalent.

Comment: Excellent, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you restrict the pair ($\epsilon, \delta$) to some subset of allowed (pairs of) positive values, nothing changes as long as

- arbitrarily small values of $\epsilon$ are allowed
- for every $\epsilon$, arbitrarily small values of $\delta$ are allowed

This allows for some dependence between epsilon and delta, although the question was about independently restricting each one to be rational.